# How to fix when files keep disappearing without reason

Tags: files, log, delete

How to fix when files keep disappearing without reason?
Or maybe because I accessed it?
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04

```
money@money:~$ ls move*
move2.sh  movenew.sh  movestart3.sh
money@money:~$ cat move2.sh
cat: move2.sh: No such file or directory
money@money:~$ ls move*
movenew.sh  movestart3.sh
money@money:~$
```

Is there a log of systematically deleted file or something?
My .bash_history also gone sometimes but got it back after a restart. Any clue?

Comment: Do you have some special or unusual install of Ubuntu or old hardware? How is your system different in any way from a stock install on an ext4-formatted, reasonably new hard drive or SSD?

Comment: No clue. This is worrying - my files don't randomly disappear. The two most obvious reasons I can think of is hardware failure or malware.. 

Comment: malware on linux?

Comment: Yes? As you noted, I didn't try to answer your question directly. I stated that the most obvious reasons I could think of for mysteriously disappearing files were those two. But your question lacks considerable detail for anyone to act on. If you can rule out malware, I would guess your harddrive is dying. Or maybe someone can provide another reason I'm not aware of..

Comment: 6 year old article for reference: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/killdisk-ransomware-now-targets-linux-prevents-boot-up-has-faulty-encryption/ Malware can also be some "friend" who put a script on your PC that randomly deletes files. How are we to know what has happened on your computer?

Comment: Please list output of `type cat` in your question. Thanks.

Comment: Please add a detailed view of your filesystem. Add output of either `tree` or `ls -la` to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your files haven't disappeared and I doubt that you have a virus.

The command `ls` lists the contents of a directory. In order to access the files listed, you must change directories, `cd`, to the directory. Please try:

```
cd move*
cat move2.sh
```

Comment: I don't think the OP has malware either - but I still don't understand this answer. How do you explain that the same command (`ls move*`), run from the same directory, produces 2 different results (`move2.sh` is absent from the latter)? Also, should there be a directory named `move*`?

Comment: There probably should not be a directory with an asterisk, commonly used as a wildcard. However, if there were two or more directories named , for example, move, move1 and move2, the result of `ls` would have shown it. I have no explanation for the different result of `ls`.

Comment: I just got the crazy idea that the OP's `cat` command has an alias that deletes the file.- asked for clarification..